# Is it possible to format the labels using set_xticklabels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In order to set the labels of an axis object, one uses the `xticklabels` method:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.eye(101))
labels = np.linspace(2, 4, 4)
ax.set_xticks([0, 33, 66, 100])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Which gives:

[image: 1]

It is also possible to format the labels using a [formatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels = np.linspace(2, 4, 4)
ax.imshow(np.eye(101))
ax.set_xticks([0, 33, 66, 100])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

But the formatter only uses the tick position, and not his label:

[image: 2]

The workaround is to manually format the labels before using `set_xticklabels`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels = ["{0:.1f}".format(x) for x in np.linspace(2, 4, 4)]
ax.imshow(np.eye(101))
ax.set_xticks([0, 33, 66, 100])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

[image: 3]

So, there are two questions:

1. Is it possible to format to the labels when using `set_xticklabels` function? For example, by using a format string.
2. What is the link between `set_xticklabels` and the [Formatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting)? It appears that the Formatter is not taking `set_xticklabels` at all into account, and produces the labels by itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the xticklabels is equivalent to using a `FixedFormatter`.

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
```

is the same as

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter(ticks))
```

(see [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L1597))

If you have set the ticklabels and then set a formatter, it will simply overwrite the previously set ticklabels. And vice versa.

Because `set_xticklabels` uses a `FixedFormatter` and not e.g. a `FormatStrFormatter`, you need to format the ticklabels yourself. In that sense, using a `FormatStrFormatter` might be the better method than using a preformatted list.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another alternative, by using the `extent` parameter of the `imshow` function: If you just want an automatic position and format for the ticks, it will handle everything for you:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.eye(101), extent=[2, 4, 2, 4])
```

[image: 1]

Just be careful to arrange your matrix in the good order: with `extent`, the minimum tick values on the x and y axes will always be on the bottom-left corner! (So `matrix[-1, 0]`).

Answer (score 1):

By now (tested on matplotlib 3.4.2) you can also use the `.format_ticks` method of a `Formatter`.

```py
ax.set_xticklabels(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f').format_ticks(ticks))
```

The `Formatter` formats the ticks before passing them to `set_xticklabels`.