# Add and format pandas timestamp labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056579/is-it-possible-to-format-the-labels-using-set-xticklabels-in-matplotlib), but instead of numeric x-axis labels, I'm struggling to add timestamp labels. As an example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


idx = pd.date_range("2023-06-15", "2023-06-16", freq="1min", inclusive="left")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(idx), 5), index=idx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(df.transpose(), aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

I'd specifically like to just show the time component, and say just on every 15 minute interval. I am trying to do something like

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
```

But this just gives

`Locator attempting to generate 138241 ticks ([-0.5, ..., 1439.5]), which exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS (1000).`

I've tried and failed with various auto formatters and locators. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23142190) a bit, while increasing the `figsize`.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))

x_lims = mdates.date2num(idx)
extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[-1], 0, 5]

im = ax.imshow(df.transpose(), extent=extent, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0, 15, 30, 45]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Output:

[image]

Or very similarly:

```py
x_lims = mdates.date2num(["2023-06-15", "2023-06-16"])
extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[1], 0, 5]
```